# Flutter: The following NetworkImageLoadException was thrown resolving an image codec

Tags: flutter, dart

Am facing a very weird issue. I want to show a profile image from the database, by passing the user id to the url to fetch the image, but for some weird reason, the userid is not being passed, I end up with an error

> I/flutter ( 4832): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE
> ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════ I/flutter (
> 4832): The following NetworkImageLoadException was thrown resolving an
> image codec: I/flutter ( 4832): HTTP request failed, statusCode: 400,
> http://20.23.12.345:9080/api/auth/users/null/photo

This is how am doing it. When a user logins I pass the json with all user details and save them to a shared prefs, and then access the user id from the profiles page, and pass it to the url string. What am I doing wrong.

How am extracting the details from shared pref

```
 String username = "";
  String firstName = "", lastName = "";
  Image photo;
  int id;
  String token = "";
  List<int> img;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  void getName() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    username = prefs.getString("username");
    username = prefs.getString("username");
    firstName = prefs.getString("firstname");
    lastName = prefs.getString("surname");
    id = prefs.getInt("id");
    token = prefs.getString("accessToken");
    setState(() {});

  }
```

how am accessing trying to pull the image via user ID

```
    child: ClipOval(
                                          child: new SizedBox(
                                            width: 120.0,
                                            height: 120.0,
                                            child: (photo != null)
                                                ? photo
                                                : Image.network(                                                 

"http://20.23.12.345:9080/api/auth/users/$id/photo",
                                                    //{key: "$token"},
                                                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                                  ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
```

How am extracting the json and saving it to shared prefs

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var parse = jsonDecode(response.body);

  if (parse["active"] == 1)
    _BodyState.activeUser = true;
  else
    _BodyState.activeUser = false;

  print("status:" + _BodyState.activeUser.toString());

  await prefs.setString('username', parse["username"]);
  await prefs.setString('accessToken', parse["accessToken"]);
  await prefs.setString('surname', parse["surname"]);
  await prefs.setString('firstname', parse["firstname"]);
  await prefs.setInt('id', parse["id"]);
  await prefs.setBool('active', _BodyState.activeUser);
```

I will appreciate any help

Comment: it seems `prefs.getInt("id")` is returning null which can be possible if you have not the `id` in shared preferences with "id" key. As you have written, you save whole json, may be you are not saving them individually with the keys like "id", "username" etc.

Comment: Hi @Pushpendra i have updated how am extracting the json values and saving them to shared pref

Comment: That is just bad code. What you could do, is store the whole JSON (if all are valuable kv pair) and while extracting get the json again from SP and parse in a Model.

Irrespective of this, can you confirm that 
1. are you getting correct value for other items, say "username"
2. id is integer